# Problems with compositing and Shading settings

Tags: node-editor, shaders, light, compositing-nodes, hdri

There is a problem setting up the shadow of my CGI model that I want to add to the camera image on the compositing screen. I can’t intervene in the shadows.
In the tutorial I watched ([https://youtu.be/hymtATx1QXw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTvlK.jpg) **23:35**) I make the node settings in the Compositing tab, but the image I get does not change the shadows and the reflected image is different.

Not: I uploaded the HDRI image but there was no shadow so I put a point light. But I did not remove the HDRI image. If you say it may be related, I will throw the screenshot.

[image: Result after compositing settings:]

[image: Nodes more closely]

Comment: Looks like you checked the box "shadow catcher" for the robot. Try uncheck this as a start...

Comment: The other thing is to reduce the backdrop side of the floor shadow catcher to match the edge of the washing machine. This way, the shadow should match the photo real floor a little better

Comment: I looked at the shadow catcher button when the robot is selected, the button is unchecked. But when I get over it, I get a warning like this:
"cant edit this propery from a linked data block". But wasn't supposed to be checked anyway?

Comment: While only shadows should be visible on the compositing screen, I still can't see the shadows. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Not sure without detailed inspection of your blend file...

Comment: Can you suggest other possible places in the file that I should check?

Comment: I would start with a simple example. Default Scene, single plane with cube, turn on Shadow Catcher, background transparency and see how that's going in compositing... then add the robot...

Comment: Thanks bro, I solved the problem by tampering with the node settings. With factors of multiply nodes. It was not very successful, but it is good for my first job.

Comment: Great. Glad you found out some solution. Take some time to write your own answer if you can!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adjusting the settings of the screen and invert nodes.